# 3-Keys Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: java, awt, keyboard-events

I need help to create keyboard shortcuts in my Java program. As can be seen in my code below, I need to have a keyboard shortcut that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> which works properly and prints `"test"`, but the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not print `"test2"` as expected, nothing happens:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(
    new KeyEventDispatcher() {
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getID()) {
                case KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED:
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_T && 
                        e.getModifiers() == java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) {
                        System.out.print("test");   
                    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_R && 
                               e.getModifiers() == java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK &&
                               e.getModifiers() == java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK) {
                        System.out.print("test2");  
                    }       
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Have you looked a KeyStrokes (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modifiers of an `InputEvent` are a bit field, so you test them using bitwise operations, not simply `==`.  But a simpler approach is to use the `is*Down()` methods of `InputEvent`:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_R && 
    e.isControlDown() && e.isShiftDown()) {
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. For future reference, if I wanted a keyboard shortcut that was ctrl+r+t how would I do that?

Comment: I don't know whether it's possible to have a single input event that represents more than one non-modifier key at the same time, sorry...